# Issues installing .NET 3.5 framework

Tags: .net, windows-7

I am currently experiencing issues installing the .NET 3.5 framework on my work computer (running Windows 7) and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions. Currently, I have tried the dotnetfx35 file from our shared drive and attempted to download the dotNetFx35setup file from Microsoft's website at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21. 
I have also installed Visual Studio 2008 ontop of 2010, as I know 3.5 comes with. None of these have worked, however. If I check the Microsoft.NET folder in both the Program Files and Program Files(x86) directories I do not see that it has been installed. I have also checked regedit and see 2.0, 3.0, and 4.0, but no 3.5. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: What's your "issues"?  Did you get an error?  Did the installer fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with 3.5 built in. Go to add/remove programs and click "Turn Windows features on or off" from there check the box for "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn features on and off does not work for some users. It didn't for me. What I found to work is the following: 
1. I copied the Windows ISO onto a USB drive;
2. I mounted the image (right click on it, select "Mount"), and then 
3. from a dos prompt I ran the following command: 
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess  making sure I replaced the drive letter with where the ISO was on my computer.

Works every time :)